# Set location.pathname and location.search together?

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like

```
 location.pathname = "/abc"
 location.search = "name=test"
```

It ends up getting redirected to `/abc`. I want the redirection to happen to `/abc?name=test`

Answer (score 4):

Just set the `location` (or `location.href`):

```
location = "/abc?name=test";
```

Since it's a relative URL, the protocol and host will be unchanged.