# Special character "?" is converted to unicode when set in location pathname

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I have an issue where I set the window's path to `'/payment/success?username=the+users+name'` by using the following code:

```
window.location.pathname = `/payment/success?userName=the+users+name}`;
```

The issue is, that the page reloads, the actual path turns out to be:

`/payment/success/account-created%3FuserName=the+users+name`

For some reason, either JS or the browser is converting my "?" into "%3F", and I can't parse the paramater set in the url.

How can I stop it from encoding the special character?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set location.pathname and location.search together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938178/set-location-pathname-and-location-search-together)

Comment: It's not unicode, it's URL encoded. A path should not contain a query string.

Comment: you probably need to encode the url. Use this function encodeURIComponent() to encode and when you try to reuse it, use the decode version

Comment: Thank you @lusc that did solve my problem, I completely forgot that the .search parameter existed, and I didn't think of using .href to set both at the same time

Comment: Thank you @Teemu I didn't really understand what sort of encoding was going on